# How to fix the error: ValueError: endog and exog matrices are different sizes

Tags: python, sql, pandas, numpy

I'm trying to write a program in python that uses a query in SQL to collect data and make a regression model. When I try to actually create the model, however, it gives me this error.

```
import pyodbc
import pandas
import statsmodels.api as sm
import numpy as np

server = 'ludsampledb.database.windows.net'
database = 'SampleDB'
username = 'sampleadmin'
password = '+U9Ly9/p'   
driver = '{ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server}'
table = 'GooglePlayStore'

conn = pyodbc.connect('DRIVER='+driver+';SERVER='+server+';PORT=1433;DATABASE='+database+';UID='+username+';PWD='+ password)

sql1 = "SELECT ISNULL((CASE WHEN ISNUMERIC(Rating) = 1 THEN CONVERT(float, Rating) ELSE 0 END), 0) AS 'Rating', ISNULL((CASE WHEN ISNUMERIC(Reviews) = 1 THEN CONVERT(float, Reviews) ELSE 0 END), 0) AS 'Reviews', ISNULL((CASE WHEN ISNUMERIC(SUBSTRING(Size, 0, LEN(Size))) = 1 THEN CONVERT(float, SUBSTRING(Size, 0, LEN(Size))) ELSE 0 END), 0) AS 'Size', ISNULL((CASE WHEN ISNUMERIC(REPLACE(Price, '$', '')) = 1 THEN CONVERT(float, REPLACE(Price, '$', '')) ELSE 0 END), 0) AS 'Price', ISNULL((CASE WHEN ISNUMERIC(REPLACE(SUBSTRING(Installs, 0, LEN(Installs)), ',', '')) = 1 THEN CONVERT(float, REPLACE(SUBSTRING(Installs, 0, LEN(Installs)), ',', '')) ELSE 0 END), 0) AS 'Installs' FROM GooglePlayStore"

data = pandas.read_sql(sql1,conn)

x = np.array([data["Rating"], data["Size"], data["Installs"], data["Price"]]).reshape(-1, 1)
x = sm.add_constant(x)
print(x.shape)
y = np.array([data['Reviews']]).reshape(-1, 1)
print(y.shape)

fit = sm.OLS(y, x).fit() #This is where the error is occurring
```

I'm pretty sure that I know what is going wrong, but I have no idea how to fix it. I've tried several things already, but none so far have worked.

Comment: Why the `reshape`? What are outputs of `.shape`?

Comment: @Parfait I did `reshape` mostly just to see if it even did anything. This was one of the solutions someone else proposed for this problem on someone else's post and I wasn't sure if it applied to mine. The output for `.shape` is `(21682, 2)` for x and `(10841, 1)` for y.

Comment: Can you post a sample of several rows of what comes out of `read_sql` for [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/q/20109391/1422451)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out what was going wrong. It was a little bit about how I had written my x and y values, and I had to get rid of my constant variable:

```
sql1 = "SELECT ISNULL((CASE WHEN ISNUMERIC(Rating) = 1 THEN CONVERT(float, Rating) ELSE 0 END), 0) AS 'Rating', ISNULL((CASE WHEN ISNUMERIC(Reviews) = 1 THEN CONVERT(float, Reviews) ELSE 0 END), 0) AS 'Reviews', ISNULL((CASE WHEN ISNUMERIC(SUBSTRING(Size, 0, LEN(Size))) = 1 THEN CONVERT(float, SUBSTRING(Size, 0, LEN(Size))) ELSE 0 END), 0) AS 'Size', ROUND(ISNULL((CASE WHEN ISNUMERIC(REPLACE(Price, '$', '')) = 1 THEN CONVERT(float, REPLACE(Price, '$', '')) ELSE 0 END), 0), 0) AS 'Price', (ISNULL((CASE WHEN ISNUMERIC(REPLACE(SUBSTRING(Installs, 0, LEN(Installs)), ',', '')) = 1 THEN CONVERT(float, REPLACE(SUBSTRING(Installs, 0, LEN(Installs)), ',', '')) ELSE 0 END), 0) / 10) AS 'Installs' FROM GooglePlayStore"
data = pandas.read_sql(sql1,conn)

x = data.reindex(["Price", "Installs", "Size", "Rating"], axis="columns")
y = np.array([data['Reviews']]).reshape(-1, 1)

fit = sm.OLS(y, x).fit()
```

Comment: What if you used `y = data[Reviews]` which would be a pandas Series (or 1D numpy array)? Did formula style above not work (be sure to use latest `statsmodels.api`)?

Comment: @Parfait it didn't work for me, I'm not sure if it might be because of the version of `statsmodels.api` I'm using or something else, but the dimensions weren't adding up with the x, but it only worked when I did the `.reshape(-1,1)`

Answer (score 0):

Avoid `reshape` calls which may be transposing data causing mismatched sizes. Pandas DataFrames and Series (each column of DataFrame) are extensions of numpy 2D and 1D arrays. Also, `sm.OLS` can directly receive pandas objects.

```py
x = data.reindex(["Rating", "Size", "Installs", "Price"], axis="columns")
x = sm.add_constant(x) 
y = data['Reviews']

fit = sm.OLS(y, x).fit()
```

Consider even R-style formula (constant automatically added) using lower case `ols`:

```py
fit = sm.ols(formula="Reviews ~ Rating + Size + Installs + Price", data=data).fit()
```

Comment: When I use this formatting for the x and the y, the error is `ValueError: shapes (1,4) and (5,) not aligned: 4 (dim 1) != 5 (dim 0)`. The shapes also didn't look close, so I tried doing a reshape on the y value by using the same `np.array` and when I checked the shape for x and y it gave me: `(10841, 5) (10841, 1)`. I feel like this is closer than before, but I'm not sure what the 5 and the 1 are and how to make them the same value.